# Androidplot draw circle with given point and radius

Tags: java, android, geometry, androidplot

I am using androidplot with PanZoom attached:

```
PanZoom.attach(plot);
```

Therefore I can zoom in and out as it should.

What I want next is to draw a circle at a given point.
Right now I use the strokewidth to set the dimension of the circle.
But when I zoom in and out, the circle size remains the same, although it should scale according to the zoom level. So imagine I zoom in infinitely, the circle should at a certain amount of zoom level cover the whole screen.

But it does not.
How can I achieve this?
I was thinking aboud increasing the strokewidth of the circle according to the zoomlevel but I was neither able to get the zoomlevel nor to get the domain levels on the left and right side of the plot.

EDIT:
In xml folder I create a file e.g. circle.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config
fillPaint.color="#00000000"
linePaint.color="#00000000"
linePaint.strokeWidth="0dp"
pointLabelFormatter.textPaint.color="#FFFFFF"
vertexPaint.color="#371cd1d4"
vertexPaint.strokeWidth="20dp"/>
```

and in java

```
    sigmaLabelFormatter = new LineAndPointFormatter();
    sigmaLabelFormatter.setPointLabelFormatter(new PointLabelFormatter());
    sigmaLabelFormatter.configure(activity.getApplicationContext(), R.xml.circle);
    sigmaLabelFormatter.setPointLabelFormatter(null);
```

Comment: What's your code for creating the circle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem, since I finally managed:

> to get the domain levels on the left and right side of the plot.

or to be more precise to get the width of the plot.

Since the dimensions of the plot is in meters, I do the calculation as follows:

```
private float calculateDP(float px){        
  return px / (densityDpi / densityDefault);
}

private float pixelsPerMeter(float value){
    float w = plot.getGraph().getWidgetDimensions().canvasRect.width();
    float w2 = plot.getBounds().getWidth().floatValue();
    return value * (w / w2);
}

private void init(Activity activity){
    densityDpi = activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
    densityDefault = android.util.DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT;
}

private void onCreate(){
// ... lots of stuff
labelFormatter.getVertexPaint().setStrokeWidth(calculateDP(pixelsPerMeter(2)));
}
```

Might it help somebody out there...

Answer (score 0):

Zoom only affects the drawing of XYSeries data; if you draw directly on the canvas, it will be drawn exactly where you specify on the canvas regardless of pan/zoom.

One thing you can do though is to make series to represent your circle and draw the circle there.  This will make the circle respond to both pan and zoom actions.  The tricky part will be picking enough points to ensure that the circle appears smooth at your highest supported zoom level.

Comment: Hi,
I am really happy about the PanZoom and so on, the only thing is, the circle remains the same size in pixels. 

But when I zoom in, I would like the circle to become bigger and vice versa.

I see your point about representing the circle as points. The only problem is, that the circle is dynamic, so it changes a lot.

You can clearly see my problem if you run the sample app of androidplot. I would like the bubbles in the bubble chart example to change their size depending on the zoom level...

Comment: ah i thought you were just drawing circles onto the canvas...didn't realize you were using bubble series.  what you want to do is possible - ill update my answer once im at a place where i can write some code :p

Comment: I had a chance to play with this a little today and quickly ran into a complication; because domain/range are often totally independent scales/value types and can zoom independently, there's no easy way to scale the bubble size purely based on zoom without either limiting the bubble scaling to zoom events on a single axis, or adding additional properties to the series defining a kind of scale coefficient for each axis.  Do you know which of these approaches would best fit your use case?

Comment: Hi Nick,
which type of zoom do you use?
I am using the following:

        `panzoom = PanZoom.attach(plot);
        panzoom.setZoom(PanZoom.Zoom.SCALE);`